# Misspelled tag 'plutusplaygroun'

Tags: discussion

The tag 'plutusplaygroun', recently created by a questioner, is misspelt.

It should be corrected to 'plutus-playground' or 'playground', or deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have merged the misspelled tag as suggested with the plutus-playground tag. I also merged the plutusplayground tag with plutus-playground.

Thanks for bringing this to attention.